# Can ping router and be pinged but cannot open webpage

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Windows 10 with a wired and wireless ethernet, which was working fine but cannot find a change that caused this.

Connected via the wired or wireless ethernet to my router:

- It can ping 192.168.0.1, and other connected local device IPs, and can be pinged from another device
- But trying to open the router webpage at http://192.168.0.1/ times out, I also cannot ping google.com etc.
- From another device, I can open the page and see the windows machine listed as a connected device.
  And other devices are working fine on the same network.

`ipconfig /renew` regenerates the same IP address and still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

1.Please first run "ipconfig /all" to check the default gateway. If it is not 192.16.0.1 then the router address changed. Type in the default gateway address in your browser to access the router.

2.**Make sure you're using the right protocol.** Some routers can be configured to only permit administration over HTTPS, and may not have an appropriate HTTP->HTTPS redirect in place. So, if http://router-ip/ doesn't work, try https://router-ip/.

3.**Try a different browser.** Some routers don't play nice with all browsers or browser extensions. The most universally-compatible is usually IE.

4.**Factory Reset** If all else fails, just push the little red button and hold it for about 30 seconds. Bear in mind that this will of course erase any custom configuration you've done to the router, including administrator passwords and IP ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a wired connection, make sure your wifi is turned off and that you don't have any other network adapters enabled.
For some routers you have to use https instead.
Make sure the clock of your computer is set correctly, sometimes that can screw things up too.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting successfully to another wireless router, I found that it was not the computer at fault but the router.
A reboot of it solved the issue, although still not sure why it went wrong.

Comment: glad you solved the problem!